# Zend 1 - Render view to variable returns empty string

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have two functions within a controller. Action which it loaded after calling the controller `indexAction()` and private function which sets data to *view* called `generateInvoice($id)`.

```
        public function indexAction() {
           $this->generateInvoice('48313');
           var_dump($this->view->tax); // prints tax, view has desired data
           $htmlcontent = $this->view->render();
           $this->setNoRender();
           var_dump($htmlcontent); // returns string '' (length=0)
         }

         private function generateInvoice($id) {
            $this->view->id = $id;
            $this->view->other_variables = $their_values;
            ...
         }
```

After calling this, Zend var dumps me just an empty string. However, when I remove `$this->setNoRender();`, my **index.phtml** file is loaded and everything renders just fine - unfortunately, not into my variable, but it gets printed on the screen, which I don't want.

I didn't find any hint online, why `$htmlcontent = $this->view->render();` doesn't work in my case. Any ideas?

Comment: I think this may be of help http://stackoverflow.com/a/10343738/1207346

Comment: Yes, that was it. I thought that controller has link to the view script, obviously I was wrong. Thank you very much and sorry for such a trivial question. Should've tried this out sooner.